# ElasticSearch - Fuzzy Keyword Match

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

I'm looking for a way to fuzzy match against a field where the words are equal.

ie. if I have a field with values like so:-

```
foobar
foobar number2
barfoo
barfoo number2
```

and I search with `fooba` I would like to only return the document `foobar` and not `foobar number2`

If I search with `number2` I would like to not return anything as both `number2` values have 2 words.

I know a term query can't be fuzzy. Is this possible with any query?

I'm using elasticsearch 5.4

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fighting with this for 2 days I worked it out after 20 mins of posting the question.

You need to create a custom analyzer for the field using the [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) tokenizer:-

```
"analyzer": {
   "all_words_analyzer": {
      "filter": [
          "lowercase"
      ],
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "keyword"
   }
}
```

Then set that on the field:-

```
"term": {
    "type": "text",
    "analyzer": "all_words_analyzer"
}
```

now a normal fuzzy match will work as above.

```
"query": {
   "fuzzy": {
       term": {
           "value": "fooba"
       }
   }
}
```